How to prevent darkened overlapping of text with reduced letter spacing in html/css

The text upon overlapping darken as in letter 'R' and 'A'. I want either to be on top of the other(or any other way to prevent this).
My code


.gradient-text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.gradient-text {
  font-size: 10rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(86deg, #FBFF6B 15.27%, #D66A6A 51.02%, #A600F4 99.78%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.18);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  letter-spacing: -1.1rem;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
<div class="centered">
  <div class="gradient-text-wrapper">
    <span class="gradient-text">Gradient</span>
  </div>
</div>



I assume that the darkened spots are because of the translucent text-fill, which is necessary :(.
I used this approach for gradient text because the actual thing is part of something bigger (for getting a text-shadow i have the same text behind this in actual project).

Depending on what browser you need to support you could use color-mix in the gradient, to mix in the color there instead of overlying it with transparancy.


.gradient-text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.gradient-text {
  font-size: 10rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  --color: rgba(255, 0, 0);
  --weight: 18%;
  background: linear-gradient( 86deg, color-mix(in srgb, var(--color) var(--weight), #FBFF6B) 15.27%, color-mix(in srgb, var(--color) var(--weight), #D66A6A) 51.02%, color-mix(in srgb, var(--color) var(--weight), #A600F4) 99.78%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  letter-spacing: -1.1rem;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
<div class="centered">
  <div class="gradient-text-wrapper">
    <span class="gradient-text">Gradient</span>
  </div>
</div>




You may just use mix-blend-mode instead background-clip. ( from when Firefox did not supported yet background-clip:text )
here is the idea with a background image on html:


.gradient-text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient( 86deg, #fbff6b 15.27%, #d66a6a 51.02%, #a600f4 99.78%);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;  /* here picked up to mix with html background, up to your choice  */
}

.gradient-text {
  display: block;
  font-size: clamp(40px, 18vw, 10rem);/* for the demo, make it fully visible inside snippet */
  padding-inline: 0 .5em;  /* > negative letter-spacing, to increase with text lenght */
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  letter-spacing: -.11em; /* for demo keep the ratio */
}


/* demo */

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/46/3264/2448) center / cover;
}
<div class="gradient-text-wrapper">
  <span class="gradient-text">Gradient</span>
</div>



a translucent drop-shadow to text could also be added https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gONLBjx


Note that the color-mix methode is in my own opinion the most efficient here

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz for the fun of it, wanted to test that filter: often brinnging up bugs in Firefox ... SO is also a good place for feedbacks ;)

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz the color-mix method worked as intended as I needed a translucent text fill too!

To prevent the darkening effect on overlapping parts of the letters while maintaining the gradient and translucent text fill, you can use a combination of ::before pseudo-elements and opacity to achieve a cleaner result. This method involves layering a non-translucent version of the text behind the translucent one.

Can you expand on this a bit more please?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.



 .gradient-text-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    }

    .gradient-text {
      font-size: 10rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      background: linear-gradient(86deg, #FBFF6B 15.27%, #D66A6A 51.02%, #A600F4 99.78%);
      background-clip: text;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      letter-spacing: -0.5rem; 
    }

    .centered {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.18);
    }
<div class="centered">
    <div class="gradient-text-wrapper">
      <span class="gradient-text">Gradient</span>
      <span class="overlay">Gradient</span>
    </div>
  </div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can, for example, use mix-blend-mode:screen;. I also assume that the spaces between the letters are intentional...


.gradient-text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.gradient-text {
  font-size: 10rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(86deg, #FBFF6B 15.27%, #D66A6A 51.02%, #A600F4 99.78%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  letter-spacing: -1.1rem;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
<div class="centered">
    <div class="gradient-text-wrapper">
      <span class="gradient-text">Gradient</span>
    </div>
</div>



